# Templated Function Pointer Explanation

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I'm confused by what's happening here and I was hoping that one of you gurus could help me understand. I've distilled this class to the methods that seem relevant, hopefully I didn't miss anything.

```
template < int* ( foo::*member_function )( void ) >
class bar
{
public:
    int myFunc( foo* myFoo )
    {
        int* result = ( myFoo->*member_function )();
        return *result;
    }
};
```

I don't understand how this has any idea what member_function is, there is no variable, yet it's being called, and someone help me out here?

Comment: The non-type template parameter is `int* ( foo::*member_function )( void )`. `member_function` is the name and `int* ( foo::* )( void )` is the type.

Comment: @Simple: building on this, `int * (foo::*)(void)`, equivalent to `int* (foo::*)()`, is a method of `foo`, which takes no parameter and returns `int*` (a pointer to `int`).

Comment: So you guys are saying my bar constructor will look like: `bar< &foo::aFooFunc > myBar;`

Comment: @JonathanMee: supposing that `aFooFunc` takes no argument and returns `int*`, yes. *And if you find the notation cryptic, you're not the only one...*

Comment: @Matthieu M. I know that C++11 finally added the functional library, that lets us leave the old function pointer definition style. (It just puts a little more love in all our hearts for C++11.)

Comment: @JonathanMee: actually, we still need old style function pointers for a number of things; for example, you cannot use a `std::function<...>` as a non-type template parameter. The notation is still... special though :)

Comment: @Matthieu M. I don't think I'm following what you mean by, "a non-type template parameter". I know that a `std::function` can be used as a templatized parameter, so that must not be what you're talking about. Are you saying that I cannot pass a `std::function` object as a regular function parameter?

Comment: @JonathanMee: `template <typename T>` => `T` is a type parameter. `template <int N>` => `N` is a non-type parameter (it's a value). Only some things are allowed as non-type parameters, including pointer to functions but excluding any user-defined class (such as `std::function<...>`) so you could not implement your template class with a `std::function<...>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`member_function` is the name of the template parameter given in:

```
template < int* ( foo::*member_function )( void ) >
```

That is, the template parameter `member_function` is a member function of `foo` that takes no arguments and returns an `int*`.

If an object of type `bar` is created with something like `bar<&foo::a_member_function> b;`, then the `member_function` template parameter is set to the member function `foo::a_member_function`. Then, when you call `myFunc`, passing it a pointer to a `foo`, it will call that member function on that `foo`.

Answer (score 6):

There are a limited number of kinds of *data* you can actually pass as template arguments; that is, not all template arguments need to be types:

> `[C++11: 14.1/1]:` A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following (optionally *cv-qualified*) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.

You have shown an example of passing a pointer-to-member as a template argument.